# @loader_path/libmex.dylib in matlab PROBLEMA

Tags: matlab

ejecutar archivos de la toolbox MVPA-Ligth-master pero el sistema me genera este error al ejecutar un .m de ejemplo:

**Invalid MEX-file
'/Users/juanjosejimenezfernandez/Desktop/Doctorado/PROGRAMAS/fieldtrip-master/external/dmlt/external/utils/nanstd.mexmaci64':
dlopen(/Users/juanjosejimenezfernandez/Desktop/Doctorado/PROGRAMAS/fieldtrip-master/external/dmlt/external/utils/nanstd.mexmaci64,
6): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libmex.dylib
Referenced from:
/Users/juanjosejimenezfernandez/Desktop/Doctorado/PROGRAMAS/fieldtrip-master/external/dmlt/external/utils/nanstd.mexmaci64
Reason: image not found**

He podido identificar el error gracias a este mismo foro y es problema de incompatibilidad de versiones matlab, ya que al parecer esa un programa ya copilado.

El problema que tengo ahora, es que no puedo solucionarlo como se indica:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458660/library-not-loaded-loader-path-libmex-dylib-in-matlab

Y no se como avanzar, os agradezco mucho la ayuda y el interés, que vaya bien Juanjo.

Comment: Ya he podido solucionarlo,

1) Debes descargarte Xcode como app

2) Reajusta el ejecutable

3) Ejecutar mex ... en la terminal de Matlab

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funcionamos aquí y para recibir la mejor ayuda posible. En tu pregunta nos debes decir que has intentado, que no te ha funcionado, que errores te ha dado, para que podamos considerarla una pregunta válida. Si no lo haces representa que **no has hecho nada** y puedes recibir [votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874) por ello, y tu pregunta puede quedar [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) pronto. Gracias por colaborar.